# MUI X Data Grid active filters

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

How can I get list of "active" filters from MUI X Data Grid?

Looking at source code I found something like this:

node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/components/toolbar/GridToolbarFilterButton.js:47

```
  const activeFilters = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridFilterActiveItemsSelector);
```

Is there any way to invoke this in my code?